# Selecting layers from within the layers without using the mouse

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers

I'd like to select a number of layers within the layers panel. Usually this is done by manually CMD + Clicking / Shift + Clicking the layers. To increase speed and productive though I prefer to say clear from the mouse. Is there a way this can be done without my hands leaving the keyboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Option/Alt</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd> (or <kbd>]</kbd>)

This will select layers while walking up or down (depending upon <kbd>[</kbd> or <kbd>]</kbd>) the layer stack in the **Layers Panel**.

There is no way to skip a single layer with this method. The layer selection will always be contiguous.

Let go of <kbd>Shift</kbd> to simply move up and down within the **Layers Panel** and highlight only one layer.

Comment: Amazing thanks! Is there way to deselect? So in other words If I'm at the topmost layer and wanted to deselect the following 2. Cycling through using the first shortcut didn't seem to do the trick.

Comment: You can't de-select with the keyboard other than to let go of shift and de-select everything but one layer. It's not perfect by any means. But as far as I know, this is the only way to highlight multiple layers in the Layers Panel with the keyboard.

Comment: Does that also apply for deselecting all as well?

Comment: No. If all layers are selected, you need a click to deselect.

Comment: You're very welcome. :) Just in case... Adding Command/Ctl with the [ and ] will *move* layers, if you aren't aware of that. And Command/Ctrl + Option/Alt will *duplicate* layers.

Comment: Knew about shifting layer position and was pretty surprised that I was only a key away from doing what I needed XD. I also found an alternative to duplicating with CMD + J.